# CORS Issue with Stripe API using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, cors, stripe-payments

I am new to both Stripe API and CORS concept.
I basically send a **POST** request from Angular to my Node js server. The client origin is different to server destination so I have implemented CORS at server side. Using a network tab on Chrome, I can see a preflight request going OK then the actual request failing. I do not actually know what went wrong with it. Could anybody give me some advice or explain what I am missing here? Thank you in advance

**Preflight Request (OPTIONS)**
[image]

**Actual Request (POST)**
[image]

**Client Side (Angular)**
[image]

**Server Side (Node JS) - cont.**
[image]

**Server Side (Node JS)**

[image]

Comment: you are sending a dom element as data. That is very wrong. Problem has nothing to do with CORS but handling of the actual post

Comment: This kind of error indicates that your server post handler is crashing out. Start by just console logging the request body inside the post handler and go from there. @charlietfl suggestion may be the culprit - your server might be choking on this data

Comment: You're getting a 503 error, so this is a server-side error (which may be due to the contents of your request), and has nothing to do with CORS (if it were, it wouldn't even reach the server). Doesn't seem to have much to do with Stripe either.

Answer (score -2):

- How do you set up the domain?
- Did you use another HTTP server as a proxy?
- Please check if node is running, and if yes check your HTTP server is too.
- Maybe your node crashed or is just not running.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37832844/node-js-consistently-giving-503-error) answer

Something else you could do is try and hit the URL directly using `localhost:XXXX/path` using `CURL` or Postman and see if the server is responding.

**Also, I see that your `content-type` is HTML. Is that correct or should it be `application/json`? I say this because you said the pre-flight went in fine. This is a known issue with CORS requests**

Comment: OPTIONS request succeeds so server is available

Comment: Try the suggestion about content type.