# Reverse proxy to node js throwing 503?

Tags: node.js, apache, reverse-proxy, centos7

**Edit:** See my answer. I found the solution, but I'll leave this up as reference.

I'm on CentOS 7 with Apache 2.4.6

I'm trying to have a subdomain of mine redirect to a node.js express web server. The node server is listening on port 8080 and I can use `wget http://localhost:8080` to download the page I want to load, so to me that means the problem I'm having is with the Apache proxy.

I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541182/apache-redirect-to-another-port) which led to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/195611/how-do-i-redirect-subdomains-to-a-different-port-on-the-same-server/195831#195831), and then also tried the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37832844/node-js-consistently-giving-503-error), but I'm still getting a 503 "Service unavailable" page when I visit the URL.

This is my virtual host for that subdomain (actual url changed):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName foo.example.com

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off

  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/

</VirtualHost>
```

I worried mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http weren't enabled even though `httpd -M` showed `proxy_module (shared)` and `proxy_http_module (shared)` in the list, so I've added the following lines to httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

If there is anything obvious I'm doing wrong, or if there's any more information that would be helpful, please let me know! Thanks!

Comment: Make sure your nodejs server is running with correct port

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading into the comments on one of the linked threads got my answer. I used the comment `this caused an error "Service Unavailable" on my httpd until I did /usr/sbin/setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1` from [vladkras](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1713660/vladkras).

Comment: @PaulSerre Sure, it's the first link in my original post, which is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541182/apache-redirect-to-another-port)